# IPv4 Network ID & Host ID

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4, cisco, cisco-ios

**[I did my research]**

I read the IPv4 and Subnetting chapters in the CCNA prep material. Watched several youtube videos and read through several forums. However, I still have a small issue because different sources use certain terms interchangeably however I want to be certain and confirm my understanding to avoid confusion.

**[The Question]**

Q1
    Is the network address the same as the node address the same as the  network id ?

Q2
    Is the host address the same as the  host id?

for instance: 
in this ip 184.19.39.34  is 184.19 the network address == the node address == the  network id?

is 39.34 the host address == the host id?

Thanks alot guys !

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Basically, yes. You should note though that there are different kinds of network addresses such as IP addresses, subnet addresses/prefixes, or MAC addresses. The exact meaning of each term depends on context.

Q2: If the IP address/mask is 184.19.39.34/16 then 184.19.0.0/16 is the subnet address. 39.34 is the *host part* of the IP address while 184.19 is the *network part*. The IP address is split into these parts as indicated by the CIDR value or the network mask (255.255.0.0 for /16).

Note that this split is only relevant for routing and on the last hop, so you don't need to know the mask value of a far IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Q1 :
yes, But on as desired of the Mac or virtual IP or a value for the IP

Answer Q2 :
Gluttony complement each other
You can find a detailed answer here :
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ip-addressing-introduction-and-classful-addressing/][1]